# my variable "totAmount" shifts one line below in my text file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've a little problem but I don't know how to resolve it.

Here is my code :

```java
    // Chargement du fichier Excel
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(outputFile + "\\firstConvert.xlsx"));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    // Ouverture du fichier texte pour écriture
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile + "\\HVEN.txt"));
            
    // variables pour stocker la valeur de la colonne "Bill" et la somme des valeurs de la colonne "Amount"
    String prevBill = "";
    double totalAmount = 0.0;

    // commencer à la ligne 1 (i=1) au lieu de 0 (première ligne)
    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                
        // Vérification de la valeur dans la colonne "Cl"
        String cl = "";
        if (row.getCell(0).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            cl = String.valueOf((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            cl = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        }
        if (cl.equals("600") || cl.equals("610") || cl.equals("620")) {
            // passe à la ligne suivante si la valeur est 600, 610 ou 620
            continue;
        }
 
        // Récupération des valeurs des colonnes
        String bill = "";
        if (row.getCell(5).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            bill = String.valueOf((int) row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            bill = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
        }
        // Définition de la valeur de la variable nomJournal en fonction de la valeur de la colonne "Bill"
        String nomJournal = "";
        if (bill.startsWith("Bill")) {
            nomJournal = "VEN";
        } else if (bill.startsWith("Credit note")) {
            nomJournal = "CVEN";
        } else if (bill.startsWith("Invoice")) {
            nomJournal = "IVEN";
        }
        String onlyNumb = bill.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

        String matchNo = "";
        if (row.getCell(15).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            matchNo = String.valueOf((int) row.getCell(15).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            matchNo = row.getCell(15).getStringCellValue();
        }

        String closedDate = "";
        if (row.getCell(4).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            closedDate = String.valueOf(row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            closedDate = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
        }

        String numTVA = "";
        if (row.getCell(8).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            numTVA = String.valueOf(row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            numTVA = row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
        }
        if(numTVA.startsWith("BE")){
            numTVA = numTVA.substring(2);
        } else {
            numTVA = "N/A";
        }

        String customer = "";
        if (row.getCell(10).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            customer = String.valueOf(row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            customer = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
        }

        double amount = 0.0;
        if (row.getCell(14).getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
            amount = row.getCell(14).getNumericCellValue();
        } else {
            amount = Double.parseDouble(row.getCell(14).getStringCellValue());
        }

        // Récupération de l'année et du mois de la colonne "Closed"
        // Conversion de la chaîne de caractères en double
        double closeDate = Double.parseDouble(closedDate);
        // Conversion de la valeur double en objet java.util.Date
        Date javaDate = DateUtil.getJavaDate(closeDate, false);
        // Formatage de la date en "jj/mm/yyyy"
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(javaDate);    

        String[] closedDateParts = formattedDate.split("/");
        String year = closedDateParts[2];
        String month = closedDateParts[1];

        // si la valeur de la colonne "Bill" est la même que celle de la ligne précédente,
        // ajouter la valeur de la colonne "Amount" à la somme des valeurs pour cette facture
        if(bill.equals(prevBill)){
            totalAmount += amount;
        } else {
            // si la valeur de la colonne "Bill" est différente de celle de la ligne précédente,
            // écrire la ligne précédente avec la somme des valeurs pour cette facture (si elle existe)
            String totAmount = Double.toString(totalAmount).replace(".", ",");

            // Écriture de la ligne dans le fichier texte avec le format demandé
            String line = "\"" + nomJournal + "\";" 
                                + "\"" + year + "\";"
                                + "\"" + year + "\";" 
                                + "\"" + month + "\";"
                                + "\"" + onlyNumb + "\";" 
                                + "\"" + formattedDate + "\";"
                                + "\"C\";" 
                                + "\"" + numTVA + "\";" 
                                + "\"" + formattedDate + "\";"
                                + "\"" + totAmount + "\";"
                                + "\"" + customer + "\";"
                                + "\"" + matchNo + "\";"
                                + "\"S\";";
            writer.println(line);
            // réinitialiser la somme des valeurs pour la facture en cours
            totalAmount = amount;
            // sauvegarder la valeur de la colonne "Bill" pour la ligne en cours
            prevBill = bill;
        }
    }
    // Fermeture du fichier texte et du fichier Excel
    writer.close();
    excelFile.close();

    System.out.print("HVEN.txt créé !");
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is my data from outputFile:

```
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"01";"202300005";"20/01/2023";"C";"0629745675";"20/01/2023";"0,0";"Mieke De keersmaecker";"1";"S";
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"01";"202300047";"30/01/2023";"C";"N/A";"30/01/2023";"254,5";"Dick Schuurman";"2";"S";
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"02";"202300050";"01/02/2023";"C";"0445907418";"01/02/2023";"278,5";"Bert Labaere";"3";"S";
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"02";"202300051";"01/02/2023";"C";"N/A";"01/02/2023";"297,0";"Elodie Baranger";"4";"S";
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"02";"202300052";"01/02/2023";"C";"N/A";"01/02/2023";"122,5";"Bert Labaere";"5";"S";
"VEN";"2023";"2023";"02";"202300053";"01/02/2023";"C";"N/A";"01/02/2023";"-38,5";"Panepinto Rebecca";"6";"S";
```

We see on the first line the value `0,0` just before `Mieke` and in fact it should be 254,5 (i.e. value of the line just after).

I want move up the value `totAmount` just above.

Comment: Can't say for the fact I'm not in a good place to think at this time, but the following line may be some trouble.    if(bill.equals(prevBill)).   e.g if they bought exactly the same again!  And if the program variable initialised at nothing and updates too late.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question and post contents of file `firstConvert.xlsx`? Maybe post it as text in form of comma-separated values, i.e. CSV.

Comment: or in other words (as @Abra used): [mcve] please :)

Answer (score 0):

`prevBill` is an empty string initially. Therefore, in the first iteration, the program will always evaluate `if(bill.equals(prevBill))` as false.

Asa result, for the first line, `totalAmount` will not be updated (the `amount` will not be added) and the row will line will be written to the file.

Comment: I have already tried to initialize it with the first line to avoid the false but suddenly the program does not write the first line.

Comment: It's a very bad process to write it like a running script, break it into a set of methods to call so you can make finalised and coherent results from each step by each method. You will also get the benefit of shielding global variables from false update by using local variables inside methods.